# Why can't TypeScript see that a nested value cannot be undefined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

TypeScript should be able to infer from a ternary operator that a specific nested value cannot be undefined. But it does not. It only works if I insert the null-assertion operator `!` into the code to indicate that a value is not null or undefined.

I have a functional react component with a `props` interface with an `accounts` field.

```
export interface IAccountState {
  [key: string]: {
    address?: string;
  };
}

accounts: IAccountState;
```

In the return statement I have a ternary operator that checks if the value is undefined.

```
{!this.props.accounts[this.props.network] || this.props.accounts[this.props.network].address === undefined ? (
<div/>) : (
  <OtherComponent
    address={this.props.accounts[this.props.network].address}
  />
)
```

Here I get the error.

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

But I think the TypeScript compiler **should** be able to see that the address value cannot be `undefined` due to the ternary operator.

I use TypeScript 3.9.7 and my `tsconfig.json` has `"strictNullChecks": true` set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet here is to give TypeScript something more specific to narrow the type of. Prior to that JSX expression:

```typescript
const address = this.props.accounts[this.props.network]?.address;
```

Or without the new[ish] *optional chaining* operator:

```typescript
const address = this.props.accounts[this.props.network] && this.props.accounts[this.props.network].address;
```

Then in the JSX expression:

```
{address === undefined ? (
<div/>) : (
  <OtherComponent
    address={address}
  />
)
```

[Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEEIPYFdwDKYckyA3gFDLIDaA1hAJ4BcyAzmFKAOYC6rlatTbBuIaAH5W2AEYArCAjAB6AFQB1OABstEMABVGABwhtVygNxUhcACa2optlPaceVocgDu23WBcy2Ni6cCAeyAC+VhEUFLaKWnCOyH7IiDj4YGysGFh4hMSQVvEIicmp4mBe2FB0rBxcINxWFDD4SsDYIMgwQQAUAB71bk0AlOTWOCBswRAAdFrY3IOj0bHAMMh9AITp+Vk0ldW1vMgAPmdpeZlsh3rHdLxzdg5OyAC8n8j48TCgELZxoJkMplMgACJdADkYG+bBQwDAFAiyAgWnhE2ovWwfT2NzuVRqj2e9kcbDYq2RFCAA) a playground link replicating the problem you're having with a simpler example, and [here's one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEEIPYFdwDKYckyA3gFDLIDaA1hAJ4BcyAzmFKAOYC6rlatTbBuIaAH5W2AEYArCAjAB6AFQB1OABstEMABVGABwhtVygNxUhcACa2optlPaceVocgDu23WBcy2Ni6cCAeyAC+VhEUFLaKWnCOyH7IiDj4YGysGFh4hMSQVvEIicmp4mBe2FB0rBxcINxWFDD4SsDYIMgwQQAUAB71bk0AlOTWOCBswRAAdFrY3IOj0bFTHGn2jmxsyAC8aXmZbDSV1bW8EnN2Dk5WwDDIfbc7e-sfyPjxMKAQtuNBMhlMpkAARLoAcjAXzYKGAYAoEWQEC0cIm1F62Be2ycqyRQA) showing that saving to a `const` solves it.

Comment: In JSX, we would probably use `{address && <OtherComponent address={address} />}`. React will ignore `null` and `undefined` (won't be showing up as strings on the page) and no useless empty `<div />` either.

Comment: @EmileBergeron - The OP is rendering a `<div/>` in the other case, rather than nothing. Or was that your point? It could matter in terms of flow or something...

Comment: Yeah, your answer is still right according to what OP had to begin with ;)